# Which bodily fluids are kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

The only secretion from the human body that I know to be kosher is human milk. I am curious to know which other bodily fluids are kosher.

For example, is it kosher to drink sweat or tears? What about mucus?

Assume that a person has only eaten pareve kosher food, and later vomits it out. Is this vomit kosher?

There's at least a dozen other related questions that come to mind, but I'll stop here to avoid being gratuitously gross. In general, which bodily fluids are kosher and which ones are not?

Comment: Are you only asking about the dietary laws (Kashrus) or will you accept prohibition on different grounds?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Sure, in the end, if it's prohibited, then it's prohibited, regardless of which set of laws the prohibition is categorized in.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok If you are referring to Bal Tishaktzu, that is a context dependent prohibition.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19071/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60649/759

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer the question as far as “kosher” means “allowed under the dietary laws”.

There is a prohibition of “בל תשקצו" – not to make oneself abominable, see [Vayikro 11 (43)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9912). [Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%95) has an article.

Examples mentioned there of what is included are:

> food mixed with vomit (which itself is disgusting)
>
> drinking urine

and in the words of the [Rambam](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968273/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-17.htm)

> food and drink from which the souls of most people are revolted, e.g.,
>   food and drink that were mixed with vomit, feces, foul discharges, or
>   the like.

Further one should not eat food which disgusts him whether or not it  disgusts others. (Ref 8 in the quoted article: רבנו פרץ מקורביל, הגהות סמ"ק, סימן פ).

I assume that the law applies equally to solids and liquids.

So sweat, tears and mucus depend on how disgusted you are by ingesting them (context-dependent @DoubleAA).

Vomit is prohibited by  בל תשקצו.

Comment: Vomit and feces are context dependent too. (It's just harder to think of good contexts)

Comment: Re - urine, my grandmother, a"h, told me that in Europe, doctors recommended people drink urine to cure violent coughs and sore throats. Perhaps, then, this was permitted only b/c it was for medicinal purposes? While this practice is uncommon , today (I guess Dr. Vick has found a better product?) can someone who feels that this method works, still do this?

Comment: I understand doctors used to taste urine to determine whether a patient was diabetic. (But presumably they spat it out.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, just out of curiosity, other than in some medical procedures, what would be a context in which one eating fæces would not be considered disgusting?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I haven't given it much thought. I'm just not ruling out the possibility.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - there are some mighty expensive coffee beans Kopi Luwak - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopi_Luwak   that come from being picked out of civet cat's faeces, and are considered a delicacy among some discerning coffee drinkers. It's the subject of a Question - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37696/is-kopi-luwac-civet-excreted-coffee-beans-kosher – Gary

Comment: Eeew! There's another coffee processed through elephants - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Ivory_coffee

Comment: @Gary, I don't believe that un-digested solids would count as fæces, I'd have to ask a medical professional though.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt-- somebody had to rummage through faeces to get it-and it's partly digested - that's what makes it so GOOD!.or something(yech!)...well, I guess I'd rather go through cat faeces than elephant faeces....