# How are "disgusting/repellent" foods determined/defined nowadays?

Tags: food

After reading the answers to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76219/which-bodily-fluids-are-kosher) and also [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/is-it-permitted-to-eat-dirt/16437#16437) question which list sources describing forbidden foods as ones being "revolting/repellent" to most people, I was left wondering how these forbidden foods are determined nowadays. Bodily fluids, dirt, etc, seem obvious, but what about foods such as beef tongue, which can seem absolutely disgusting to some people, especially vegetarians, but absolutely yummy to others sliced nice and thin from the tip in a big pile on good rye bread?  Or other things, like the eyeballs/cheeks of a whole steamed fish, which some folks might relish as the best parts of the fish, while others at the table might turn away in disgust. Or even gefilte fish, which seems to be absolutely revolting to some folks...

So--how is something gastronomically subjective as "revolting" determined nowadays? Is there an "official" or even "suggested" list of these foods published/promulgated by any authoritative groups?

Comment: I would think that part of this determination involves cultural as well as regional norms. E.g. grits is a popular Southern U.S. food. To me it looks like shredded Yahrtzeit candle, but when my FL friend visits me & eats it, I let him do it in my home. Perhaps, it may even involve family / Shalom Bayit issues. E.g., my wife thinks that p'tcha (aka "galla", jelled calf's feet, aspic) is so revolting that she won't let me make or eat it, despite that this was my family Yom Tov "minhag".

Comment: @DanF I enjoy my morning grits, thank you very much. You New Yorkers can keep your egg cream. :)

Comment: @DonielF Depending on how it's made, grits can be OK. But, IMO, if you haven't tried an egg cream ever in your life, you haven't really lived ;-) After you try it and you don't like it, I would be fine providing that you still like strong "2 cents plain." (Refer to Allan Sherman's "Seltzer Boy" song.)

Comment: @DanF-mmmm!  With Fox's Ubet, of course! When Jerry Garcia was doing a stand of shows on Broadway, they made great ones in the theatre.