# Who decides whether it's normal to eat something in a certain fashion?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shulchan-aruch

The Shulchan Aruch in several places writes that if something is eaten in an abnormal fashion, it gets a Shehakol rather than its usual bracha.<sup>1</sup>

What defines whether something is a "normal" way of eating something? Most of the people in a locale? In a country? In the world? Most Jews? Some other benchmark?

---

<sup>1</sup> [OC 202:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.202.3) regarding bitter fruit which was sweetened;
[202:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.202.12) regarding fruits which are normally eaten cooked but were eaten raw;
[204:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.204.4) regarding wine which soured;
[205:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.205.1) regarding vegetables which are normally eaten cooked but were eaten raw;
[208:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.208.5) regarding eating flour;
and probably elsewhere as well; feel free to add more sources if there are any.

Comment: I thought it was society. Not sure though if frum society or the national one. For example the MB says chamar medinah can change on Pesach from beer to mead, which I assume is a Jewish societal change.

Comment: @robev Define "society." Global? Local? At least that halacha rules out historical.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76246/