# Could vomit be meaty or milky?

Tags: halacha, food, health-safety-shmira

Despite the probable prohibition of eating vomit (see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76219/which-bodily-fluids-are-kosher/76236#76236) related question), would it take on the status of its prior-eaten state i.e. milky, meaty or non-kosher (for mixes of milky and meaty)?

Comment: Is this question about human vomit?  Or kosher animal vomit, like cud that might leak out?

Answer (score 3):

#### Regarding milk, according to some Rishonim yes, to some else no,  and to others it depends on the cases.

See *Gemara AZ 35a,*  there,  the Gemara discussion is about **gastric content,**  the Gemara calls it Perisha (exudate).  *See Berayta in Chulin 109b* regarding a stomach cooked when it was containing milk,  Berayta prohibited . See *Rashi and Tosfot Chulin 116b,*  Tosfot in name of Rabenu Tam  says that there are two types of gastric content,  **not fermented (or chemically altered) and fermented.**  Not fermented milk which is in stomach and the both are cooked together leads to  prohibited basar bechalav (this is the case of Berayta Chulin 109b according to Rabenu Tam).  But when the milk was already fermented,  the cooked stomach would  not be prohibited. This halacha is in **Shulchan Aruch Yore Dea 87, 9** . In Shulchan Aruch a first opinion (Rif and Rambam) says that even non fermented milk cooked in stomach would not lead to prohibition but a second opinion prohibited it. For the fermented the Shach reports several opinions,  some opinions allow to cook stomach with gastric fermented milk lechatechilla (linked to Rabenu Tam)  and some other prohibited even bediavad (Rashi,  ruled halachically by Maharshal).  It seems that the Shach concluded with the stringent opinion (perhaps lechatechilla only) ,  the Aruch Hashulchan rules as Rabenu Tam.

We learn from this that following most poskim gastric content is **denatured,**   the Gemara calls this  **"pirsha"**  (exudate )   the Baer Heytev explains as **excrement,**   disgusting thing  {but Rashi concluded in Chulin 116b that this expression says only that it is not a part of the body}.  But this is not excrement concerning the prohibition to read Shema and pray in front of it (Rabbi Akiva Eiger,  see **Mishna Berura OC 76 sk 20** ).
Anyway when the vomit is sufficiently fermented and the milk or the meat seems denatured it is not besari or  chalavi according to most opinions in poskim.

But something not fermented is milky or meaty following many poskim.

#### According to Shulchan Aruch I think that vomited milk is not milky, according to the Shach it is milky, at least lechatechilla. The RMA (according to Taz) prohibits only if the milk is not denatured (by digestion).

For meat, I assume that the same rules are applicable.

Comment: @Gary I don't understand you

Comment: vomit is expulsion of gastric content by the mouth (or nostrils)  @Gary

Comment: Reading the Wiki on ruminants...Okay, so microbes ferment the food in the first stomach chamber, then it says it's "regurgitated", not quite vomiting.  That makes sense- so all cud is by definition fermented.  You wrote about cooking the stomachs with fermented/unfermented milk in them.  How did it get back in there?  Or were they not talking about vomited gastric content in those cases? The question asks about possible definition of "something's" vomit as milky/meaty. Sorry for my confusion..

Comment: @Gary I added to the word fermented the words "chemically altered

Comment: "regarding milk"made the whole difference.  Thank you for finding/knowing this stuff!